# How can I get the element near the cursor?

Tags: javascript

Just like what I said in title.I want to target the element near the cursor.

```
 <style type="text/css">
   span{
       display: inline-block;
       min-width: 80px;
       border-bottom: 2px solid black;
   }
 </style>


<div contenteditable="true">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

When users input some words, I really want to know which  is the curson in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
// Get all span-elements
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("span_element");

// Cycle through them and add an onmouseover-function to them
for(var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {
    elements[i].onmouseover = function() {
        console.log(this.id);
    } 
}
```

Therefor your `html` should look like this for example (to adress the elements):

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  <span id="span1" class="span_element"></span>
  <span id="span2" class="span_element"></span>
  <span id="span3" class="span_element"></span>
</div>
```

---

*Side note:* With jQuery this is much more easier, as you have [.focus()](https://api.jquery.com/focus/).

*Side note 2:* Please have in mind, that there is a difference between the *mousecursor* (as described in your initial post and my answer) and the *caret position* (where the user is actually typing). Those can be different.

Comment: Oh! Yes. I forget the focus() event, and I can know which element was focused by event object.Just like event.target....Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a listener to the onmouseover event to have a function triggered when the mouse is above one of your span.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
 <span onmouseover="myFunction1()"></span>
 <span onmouseover="myFunction2()"></span>
 <span onmouseover="myFunction3()"></span>
</div>

function myFunction1() {
 // the mouse is above span 1
}
// etc...
```

Official documentation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp)

**Edit** : Modification of the answer after understanding what OP was looking for

As you use jQuery and you work with dynamically-added elements, I suggest you to use something like this :

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'div span', function() {
    $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
})
.on('mouseleave', 'div span', function() {
    $(this).css('border-color', 'black');
});
```

I created a JSFiddle sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bsgu3w83/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it can't help me.Because we don't know how many elements the parent element contains.The child element of the div can be created by users dynamically.

Comment: User cannot modify the DOM directly with the contenteditable attribute. If the user inputs "<span></span>" it will be added as text and won't draw your black strike.

Comment: Are you using jQuery ?

Comment: There will be a button, I bind an event which will add the <span></span> to the document. I'm using jQuery.But it's not the key point.

Comment: I have improved my answer

Comment: Hey, man. I have checked your demo.Emm.., I want to get the element near the cursor when the div element is focused.So I can insert the element to the location where my cursor located.Understand? My English is not very good^_^

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a generalized way of finding DOM elements near the cursor using a browser API `document.elementFromPoint(x,y)`.
I have used the approach in [this](https://dev.to/jashgopani/windows-10-grid-hover-effect-using-html-css-and-vanilla-js-42d9) article and for I have also published a package for the same on npm called [cursor-nearby-elements](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cursor-nearby-elements)